# Dynamically setting the content of a menu in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, menu, signals

I want to create a menu whose content is determined dynamically (through some data received from the network). How would I go about implementing such a menu in Qt?

The network should be queried for the content to be shown whenever the menu is opened.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a menu bar somewhere:

```
QMenu* m = new QMenu(this);
m->setTitle("click here");
m->setIcon(QIcon());
ui->menuBar->addMenu(m);
```

Comment: Menu can be easily set by the class calls at run time. Just keep the nework thread separate from the GUI so that the GUI remain responsive always.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`QMenu::aboutToShow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#aboutToShow) signal. This signal is emitted when the user opens the menu and it is the perfect moment to re-populate your menu.

Nevertheless, you have to take following things into consideration:

- The signal is emitted synchronously respect the rest of the UI, it means that once the slot handling it finishes the menu will be shown. So you have to populate the menu before returning from that function.
- This signal is emitted in the main thread (the one that handles the GUI), so the rest of the interface will be blocked until it finishes. This is important if your network connections depends on the events loop. You may use [`QApplication::processEvents`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) to be sure events are consumed.

## Basic example

The following example uses a timer instead of a network connection for the sake of simplicity, but illustrates my point:

In some initialization function (such as the constructor). The menu is assumed to already exists (similar case for context menu):

```
connect(ui.menuDynamicMenu, &QMenu::aboutToShow, this, &MainWindow::onMenuAboutToShow);
```

The slot (`m_waiting` should be an atomic boolean or similarly protected flag, in the case you want to handle the network connection using multi-threading):

```
void MainWindow::onMenuAboutToShow()
{
  // Here your _synchronous_ network query
  // Probably you'll have to use some kind of barrier
  m_waiting = true;
  QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, [this]() {
    ui.menuDynamicMenu->clear();
    ui.menuDynamicMenu->addAction("Some action from network query");
    ui.menuDynamicMenu->addAction("Another action from network query");

    m_waiting = false;
  });

  while (m_waiting) {
    qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);
  }
}
```

The full code of this example is available in [GitHub](https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/tree/master/55575530-dynamically-setting-the-content-of-a-menu-in-qt).